# How to put multiple input parameter in Google (Places) API

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, http-request-parameters

How can i put multiple languages parameter on this Google Places API, so i can get higher query priorities in the listed languages

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=places&language=
```

To be specific, i want EN, IT, DE, ES, NL

Comment: is language=en,it,de,es,nl working?

Comment: @LajosArpad i dont think so, it doesnt throw an error tho, so the API's still working...